# C# ReportParameter Class is breaking my string into different objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportparameter

I'm using ReportParameter to pass a list of Departments to a Report, but it seems like ReportParameter is breaking my comma separated string into a list of individual strings. I need to pass the actual, unmodified string as a single item. What can I do to get ReportParameter to just leave my data alone and pass it to the report?

I'm passing data to a report, and my ReportParameter call looks like this:

```
ReportParameter DepartmentName = new ReportParameter("Dept", "Bakery,Deli,Cheese", false);
```

But when I trace the call to the database, it's breaking that up into three string objects ("Bakery", "Deli", "Cheese") instead of keeping them together ("Bakery, Deli, Cheese") and the report fails. The report works if a single item is sent instead, so it is this behavior that is causing the report to fail.

Comment: based on what you are displaying sounds like the `Parameters` are a `StringCollection` and which you can think of as a `List<string>` did you read the `ReportParameter Class Documentation MSDN`...?

Comment: I have. The problem is, if I give it a string with commas, I'm getting a list of each item individually, and I don't want that. I'm not giving it a list, I'm giving it a single string object and it's somewhere turning it into a list.

Comment: what's the set look like?

Comment: Is this for report viewer? not sure if this link helps but check it out http://forums.asp.net/t/1338302.aspx?Passing+a+Multi+value+parameter+to+the+ReportViewer+control